# Using std::sort to sort an array of C strings

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to use `std::sort` to sort an array of C strings. Here's what I've done:

```
const char *tab[5];
//then fill up the tab
sort(tab, tab+5);
```

This doesn't seem to work. I've also tried using `sort(tab, tab+5, strcmp)`, which worked, but when I put it into a function, the array remains unchanged. Sorting function:

```
void sortfunc (const char *tab[], int n){
    filltab(tab, n); //n is the ammount of strings
    sort(tab, tab+n, strcmp);
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort): The comparison object expected by it has to return ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

[strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp), the function you provided has another return convention:

- Negative value if lhs is less than rhs.
- ​0​ if lhs is equal to rhs.
- Positive value if lhs is greater than rhs.

<sub>(here lhs and rhs reffer to left hand operator and right hand operator)</sub>

So you have to create your own wrapper function around strcmp.

If you could use c++11 and if you could use c++ for real (i.e. `std::string` and `std::vector`) you can use other cool tricks like lambdas.

---

The classic solution:

```
bool cmp(char const *lhs, char const *rhs) {
  return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
}

std::sort(tab, tab + n, cmp);
```

The lambda solution:

```
std::sort(tab, tab + n, [](char const *lhs,
                           char const *rhs) { return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0; });
```

The real C++ solution

```
std::vector<std::string> v = ...;

std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working. Like @bolov and @Svalorzen said, I had to write a `bool` function that returns `true` or `false`, instead of -1, 0, 1, like `strcmp()` does. Here it is, if anyone needs it in the future:

```
bool cmp(const char *str1, const char *str2){
    if(strcmp(str1, str2)<0) return true;
    else return false;
}
sort(tab, tab+5, cmp);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: whenever you see yourself doing `if (condition) return true; else return false;` then you can just return the condition itself. So, `return condition;`