# std::sort is not sorting

Tags: c++, sorting

i want modify xmrig proxy source to print workers sorted alphabetical.

added two lines of code the following method
but is not working.

```
auto pr_workers=m_workers;
    std::sort(pr_workers.begin(), pr_workers.end(), [](const Worker a, const Worker b) {
        return a.name() < b.name();
    });
```

```
void xmrig::Workers::printWorkers()
{
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        LOG_ERR("Per worker statistics disabled");

        return;
    }

    char workerName[24] = { 0 };
    size_t size = 0;

    Log::print(WHITE_BOLD_S "%-23s | %-15s | %-5s | %-8s | %-3s | %11s | %11s |",
               "WORKER NAME", "LAST IP", "COUNT", "ACCEPTED", "REJ", "10 MINUTES", "24 HOURS");

    auto pr_workers=m_workers;
    std::sort(pr_workers.begin(), pr_workers.end(), [](const Worker a, const Worker b) {
        return a.name() < b.name();
    });

    for (const Worker &worker : pr_workers) {
        const char *name = worker.name();
        size = strlen(name);

        if (size > sizeof(workerName) - 1) {
            if (m_mode == Agent) {
                memcpy(workerName, name, 20);
                memcpy(workerName + 20, "...", 3);
            }
            else {
                memcpy(workerName, name, 6);
                memcpy(workerName + 6, "...", 3);
                memcpy(workerName + 9, name + size - sizeof(workerName) + 10, sizeof(workerName) - 10);
            }
        }
        else {
            strncpy(workerName, name, sizeof(workerName) - 1);
        }

        Log::print("%-23s | %-15s | %5" PRIu64 " | %8" PRIu64 " | %3" PRIu64 " | %6.2f kH/s | %6.2f kH/s |",
                   workerName, worker.ip(), worker.connections(), worker.accepted(), worker.rejected(), worker.hashrate(600), worker.hashrate(86400));
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be using C style strings for some reason instead of normal C++ `std::string`. You can't compare C strings with `<` as they're just pointers.

Comment: See dupe: [Using std::sort to sort an array of C strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213100/using-stdsort-to-sort-an-array-of-c-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `name()` returns a `const char*` you need to use [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) to make a lexicographical comparison of the two C strings. Alternatively, you can use [`std::strcoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcoll) to compare them according to the current locale. If you do `return a.name() < b.name();` you will compare the two pointers, which will not lead to any meaningful results in this context.

This is what you should use in this case:

```cpp
return std::strcmp(a.name(), b.name()) < 0;
// or return std::strcoll(a.name(), b.name()) < 0;
```